# Regex: How to find all html lines with english words from the tags whose content is written in another language

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have this html tags:

`<p class="BEBE">着名的文学评论家Love有一些重要的东西来说，关于总是分享胜利的人才，转向他们的起源：</p>`

`<p class="BEBE">着名的文学评论家 有一些重要的东西来说，关于总是分享胜利的人才，kiss 转向他们的起源：</p>`

So I must find all lines with at least one english word from the tags whose content is written in another language (cz - chinesse for example)

**But I don't wanna find this:** (because doesn't have english words)

`<p class="BEBE">某些，真正的经济学，真正预测的是神圣的本质</p>`

My regex doesn't work, seems to find all tags:

FIND: **`<p class="BEBE">.*[^\x00-\x7F]+.*</p>`**

Or, this regex finds only those html tags that contains only chinesse words, without english.

FIND: **`<p class="BEBE">+(?!\w+[\x00-\x7F]).*</p>`**

But I need only those tags that contains at least on english word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solution, thanks @Toto

FIND: **`<p class="BEBE">+(\w+[\x00-\x7F]).*</p>`**

also, If you want to skip the tags that contain `<em>` or `</em>`

FIND: **`<p class="BEBE">+(?!\w+</em>)+\w+(\w+[\x00-\x7F]).*</p>`**

or

FIND: **`<p class="BEBE">+(?!\w+<em>).*(\w+[\x00-\x7F]).*</p>`**

Answer (score 1):

You have extra spaces in your regex:

```
<p class="BEBE">.* [^\x00-\x7F]+ .*</p>
#         here ___^    and   ___^
```

remove them:

```
<p class="BEBE">.*[^\x00-\x7F]+.*</p>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes @Toto, I update the post. But, the problem was that this regex seems to find all html tags that contains chinese words, but I need to find only those tags that contains at least one english word

Comment: I manage to make a regex that will find only chinesse words, but I need the oposite solution. To find only those tags that contains at least one english word:  **`<p class="BEBE">+(?!\w+[\x00-\x7F]).*</p>`**

Comment: @RobRob: Works for me. Have you UNchecked `. matches newline`?

Comment: yes, I don't use `.matches newline`. But my last regex, if I can find on internet the ANSII /UTF-8 regex, I believe the problem will be fix

Comment: I find the solution, post it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

some other solutions can be found [HERE:](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/21292/regex-select-all-non-ascii-characters-html-tags)

FIND: `<p class="BEBE"><em>.*[\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}\x{FF00}-\x{FFEF}]</em></p>`

**OR**

FIND: `(?<=<p class="BEBE"><em>)[\x00-\x7F]+?(?=</em>)`